# How do I show only the available options in a combo box on an Access form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm making a reservation system on Access 2010 and I have a form that reserves a table for a customer. I just input the customer's Customer ID, date and time of reservation, and the table.

Originally, my form's layout is like this:

[image]

However my professor said it wasn't efficient because you'd have to check the database just to see if the table is still available. He suggested a dropdown list of the available tables left for reservation. Also, the tables have a format of D-# or L-# depending whether it's for lunch or for dinner.

I know how to put the dropdown list and stuff but I'm not sure if I know how to update it.

My table (database) for the reservation is just the list of the reservations made on that day.

I hope someone can understand my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Microsoft help article here:

[Basing one combo box on another](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/basing-one-combo-box-on-another-HA001173058.aspx)

In your case the values in the combo box (for the table numbers) would be based on the current value of a text box (for the date), but the principle is the same:

The `Row Source` for your combo box is a query that filters the list of tables based on their availability on the date specified by the `.Value` of the "Date" text box. In the `After Update` event for the "Date" text box you tell the combo box to `.Requery` so it will list the available tables on the date in question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I found a way around it. I made a query that shows the available tables and made a combo box in my form based on the values in the query. My problem now is how I update the records.

Comment: Please be specific in what records you wish to update.  I suspect your 'way around' may have made the proper methodology (That Gord was trying to help you with) more challenging.